# "Move" mutable reference into itself

Tags: rust, move, borrow-checker

I am trying to implement a "transform" function that takes a non-copy enum value and and modifies it based on a parameter, but some of the parameters do nothing. A simplified example is:

```
enum NonCopy {
    A,
    B,
    C
}

fn transform(to_transfrom: &mut NonCopy, param: u32) -> () {
    *to_transfrom = match param {
        // transformations
        1 => NonCopy::A,
        2 => NonCopy::B, 
        // retains the value
        _ => *to_transfrom
    };
}
```

I know that since the `NonCopy` doesn't implement the Copy trait the value inside to_transform cannot be moved out, however if `param` is neither 1 or 2 the value of `*to_transform` is assigned to itself, so it stays the same and nothing should be moved, but the compiler doesn't recognize that.

How can I achieve such a pattern with an assignment to a match expression?

I know I could instead assign in the match expression, but the non-example version is bigger and I do not want to repeat so much code plus it is quite ugly.

Comment: How about [matching into an option](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=50184420a4d77932029a834db357bd6d)?

Comment: specifying that the function returns an empty tuple is not needed.

Comment: @kmdreko That's a nice solution. Although it also requires a lot of repetition and unlike assignments Some(x) needs two pastes ("Some(" and ")" per match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A neat little trick in Rust is that when you break out of an expression (via `return`, `break`, etc.), you don't actually need to provide a value for that expression. In this case, you can return from the match arm without providing a value:

```rust
enum NonCopy {
    A,
    B,
    C
}

fn transform(to_transfrom: &mut NonCopy, param: u32) -> () {
    *to_transfrom = match param {
        // transformations
        1 => NonCopy::A,
        2 => NonCopy::B, 
        // retains the value
        _ => return,
    };
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `return` returns from the **function**, not the match block, so this is not equivalent if there's any code afterwards that needs to be run.

Comment: @Aplet123 True. If you need to run code afterwards, then kmdreko's comment on the question might be the best way.

Comment: I accepted this as an answer because you can wrap it in a "fake" loop, replace the return with a break and place a break after the assignment to get the same behavior inside a larger function.

Comment: That's clever! Glad I could help.